# Jquery UI calendar in asp.net MVC 3 partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I have created a partial view in my asp.net MVC 3 application and want to create a Jquery UI calendar. I have added this javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#DateOpened").datepicker(
            {
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                yearRange: startYearRange + ':' + endYearRange
            });
    });
</script>
```

and HTML looks like this:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateAccountDetails", null))
{
 <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateOpened)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOpened)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateOpened)
                </div>

}
```

But it is not showing the Calendar. any suggestions please ?

Comment: This is not HTML, show us the actual HTML that is generated by those helpers.

Comment: in actual html, id is DateOpened

Comment: is there any other javascript on your page that is working, maybe an error is breaking your DatePicker code? check that your jquery references are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you dynamically loading the form (through some kind of ajax behaviour)? 
Is your script tag inside the partial view that renders the form?

If you load the view dynamically, then datepicker behaviour won't be attached, because it's declared before the actual field is added to DOM.

Also is your script attached to the page correctly (visible from view source)?
You can try to execute that same script code from some JS console inside browser to see if it's working. 
If it's working there, then you have issues in loading the view, meaning script gets loaded before the actual field is in DOM.

Comment: thanks, I was wondering why datepicker wasn't workin in my dynamically added popup. I went with a masked input instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you inluded a reference to the datepicker plugin script in either the contents of your partial view, or the master page it is contained in?

Comment: yes I added Jquery UI in partial view like this: <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to understand the issue since you don't actually show the HTML code that is being produced by your helpers.

But I'm quite sure the problem here is that your selector doesn't match any input element:

```
 $("#DateOpened").datepicker(...)
```

Are you sure there is a field with id `DateOpened`? Or is it the "name" property that's called like this?? Try

```
 $("*[name=DateOpened]").datepicker(...)
```

Comment: Here is the html rendered: <input class="text-box single-line valid" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Date Opened: field is required." id="DateOpened" name="DateOpened" type="text" value="1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM">

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using .EditorFor

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOpened)
```

Try

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateOpened, new { id = @DateOpened })
```